# Angular 2 - how to make a pages refreshable?

Tags: angular, nginx, routes

Have the only `index.html` physical page that serves the multiple components as virtual ones with the routings set up like this:

```
{path: 'cat/:name', component: CatComponent}
```

So, I can easily access the cat by it's name using `routingLink="/cat/tom"`. However, if I refresh the page or type the link manually in the browser address bar `http://localhost:8080/cat/tom` I get the error `404 not found`.

I know it's a common issue and Angular doc says:

> Using this mode requires URL rewriting on server side, basically you
>   have to rewrite all your links to entry point of your application
>   (e.g. index.html)

But it seems to be not that easy, where have I rewrite the url to? I expect that by refreshing the `/cat/tom` I'll get the same page and not the root one.

Have tried another way by using `HashLocationStrategy` instead of default `HTML5` and rewrote the urls to the particular resources using `nginx` like `/#/cat/tom` since they are easily accessable by straight path but there's another fail - [that's why](https://serverfault.com/questions/806609/nginx-rewrite-and-pass-proxy-to-another-port-throws-404-not-found).

How to make Angular pages refreshable? Is `nginx` a player there?

Comment: Assuming you also have a route similar to this `{ path: '', component: MainComponent }`, can you get `http://localhost:8080/` to reload successfully?

Comment: @KT., yeah, the root one is always reloads fine without any proxies like `nginx`, but it would be strange if it wouldn't. But any other paths answer `404` at any refresh or straight request

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to respond on serverfault, but my nginx location config is simple: `location / { proxy_pass  http://upstreamname; }`. Also, I don't use the `root` setting in the nginx server config. I use Angular2 and pages are refreshable.

Comment: @KT., do you have the only `index.html` or the multiple ones?

Comment: Single index.html for the ng2 app.

Comment: @KT., lol really don't know what I changed in `nginx` but it does work now. Once I understand what happened, will post the solution

Comment: You need to tell the server to redirect all requests except files (and API's for instance) to index.html at the root. If you tell me which server (nginx, node.js, iis, etc)  you're using, I can provide you the required server config for this.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it does work now.

Now it's possible to refresh the virtual location `/cat/tom` or `/cat/bob`, or access it via straight url. The refreshed page won't lose it's url and won't throw `404 not found` error.

Nginx conf:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;
    root /;

    #charset koi8-r;

    #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

    location / {
        rewrite ^/cat/([a-z]+)$ / break;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/;
    } 

    ...
}
```

The `root /;` and new `location` directive are added.

It's a fail idea to ignore `^$` at the regex or to omit the trailing backslash of `proxy_pass` address.

Everything does work as expected now.